# Скрипт, вставляющий html код

Tags: html

Я совсем нулёвочка, не могли бы вы мне подсказать, как можно написать скрипт, который будет выполняться при загрузке страницы и генерировать html-код, хранящихся в отдельном документе, и вставлять его в определённой части страницы?
Или как вставить javascript, хранящийся отдельно, вставляющий кусок html-кода?

P.S: Это нужно для сайта, в котором много страниц, в каждой из них, справа есть одинаковый раздел, который я назвала "новости". Каждый раз обновлять текст на 40 страницах не интересно, а так новости будут генерироваться сами, а мне их придётся изменять только 1 раз.

Comment: Ааа, спасибо вам за ответы!! Знаете, я с удовольствием поучусь применять всё это, только на данный момент сайт уже готов в html и запущен, осталось загрузить эту область текста с новостями, поэтому начала изучать JavaScript и так быстро освоить более глубокие его проявления не думаю, что получиться :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function{
   $('#news').load("ajax/news.html");
});
```

Используйте этот сайт про [jQuery](http://jquery.page2page.ru)

Может можно сделать чтобы не аяксом грузить а на сервере этот файл подключался в нужном месте шаблона. Самый простой пример:

```
<div id="news">
  <?php include 'news.html'; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

в jQuery есть функция load() , она как раз загружает данные из других файлов

Answer (score 0):

вставьте ваш скрипт в тег

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="PathToYourScript/namescript.js">
//Some code
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так: Например, есть страницы, на которых необходимо вывести новости. 10 страниц и на всех добавлять одну новость не совсем гуд :). Для того чтобы добавить новость один раз и вывести ее на все страницы, необходимо создать файл news.html, в нем "нарисовать" новости, а вывести их на все страницы поможет вот эта команда, которую необходимо вставить в нужное место в тех 10 страницах:

```
<!--#include virtual="/путь_к_файлу/news.html"-->
```

главное чтобы веб-сервер поддерживал SSI
Например,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Название страницы</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
<p>текст ... текст ... текст ... текст ... текст ... текст ... текст ... </p>

<h2>Новости</h2>
<!--#include virtual="/путь_к_файлу/news.html"-->

</body>
</html>
```

ну или, как говорилось выше, то можно вывести новости через javascript

Answer (score 0):

Вам лучше бы использовать странички с форматом .php, а там пользоваться функцией include(). Например

```
<? include("/blocks/menu.php")?>
```

Выведет все, что находится в файле menu.php, которая находится в папке blocks.